# Attempted to call method "sendEmailMessage" on class "Swift_Mailer"

Tags: php, frameworks

I am trying to send an email with swiftmailer.
My mailer class:

```
 <?php


namespace Src\EmailBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface;

class MailerHelper implements MailerInterface
{
public $mailer;

public function __construct($mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

/**
 * @param string $subject
 * @param string $fromEmail
 * @param string $toEmail
 * @param string $body
 */
public function sendEmailMessage($subject, $fromEmail, $toEmail,$body)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($fromEmail)
        ->setTo($toEmail)
        ->setBody($body);

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

}

My config.yml

```
mailer_helper :
    class:    Src\EmailBundle\Services\MailerHelper
    arguments: ['@mailer']
```

And in my controller:

```
$this->get('MailerHelper')->sendEmailMessage('test','test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com',"Test");
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Attempted to load class "MailerHelper" from namespace "Src\EmailBundle\Services" 
 Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

I guess the service is wrong, but Iam not sure.
Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: Your sendMessage function is protected.

Comment: I changed it to public, but I still have the same Exception.

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: Shouldn't it be $this->get('mailer_helper')?

Comment: Doesnt work.    Normally it should work I am getting this :protected function getMailerHelperService()
    {
        return $this->services['mailer_helper'] = new \Src\EmailBundle\Services\MailerHelper($this->get('swiftmailer.mailer.default'));
    }